# Storing large amount of CSV values in a matrix in C

Tags: c, csv

I am trying to store a CSV file that has 430469 rows (excluding the header) and 41 columns(excluding 2 columns of at the beginning) in a matrix in C. For that, I have declared a matrix dynamically.

The data is like this,

[image]

Where the first row contains the header. The first 2 columns contains the latitude and longitude respectively and the later rows contains the temperature recorded at those latitude and longitude in that year.

For reading the data and storing them in the matrix I have used this code snippet

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{


        //counting the number of rows and columns
        
    FILE *mf=fopen("tdata.csv", "r");
    if(mf==NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to open the file");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    char line[2000000];
    
    int r=0, c;
    
    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line), mf))
    {
        char *token;
        
        c=0;
        
        token=strtok(line, ",");
        
        while(token!=NULL)
        {
            
            c++;
            token= strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
        
        r++;
        
    }
    
    r=r-1; //since first row is header
    c=c-2; //since first 2 columns are latitude and longitude that we dont need

    printf("The number of row and column is is %d %d \n", r, c);
    
    
    
    
    //declaring the matrix of size m[r][c]
    
    double **mat = (double **)malloc(r * sizeof(double *));
        
        for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
        mat[i] = (double *)malloc(c * sizeof(double));
    
    
    
    
    
    
    // Storing the values in the matrix
    
    FILE *mf1=fopen("test.csv", "r");
    if(mf1==NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to open the file");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    
    char line1[2000];
    
    int i=0,j=0;
    
    while(fgets(line1,sizeof(line1), mf1))
    {
        char *token1;
        char *ptr;
        double ret;
                
                j=0;        
        
        token1=strtok(line1, ",");
        
        
        
        while(token1!=NULL)
        {       
        
            
            
                if(i>0 && j>1)
                {
                    double d;
                sscanf(token1, "%lf", &d);
                    mat[i-1][j-2] = d;
                }
            
            token1= strtok(NULL, ",");
            j++;
        }
        
        
        
        i++;
    }
    
    
    //Printing the matrix
    
    for (int i = 0; i <  r; i++)
    {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            {
                printf("%lf ", mat[i][j]);
            }
            
            printf("\n");
         }
    
    
    //printf("%lf ", mat[23][0]);
    
    
    
    
    //finding the minimum in every year.
    
    //To find the minimum of every year, we must at first declare an array having the size as total number of columns
    
     double* arr;
     arr = (double*)malloc(c * sizeof(double));
     
     double min;
     
     for (int j = 0; j <  c; j++)
     {
        min=1000;
            for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
            {
                if(mat[i][j]<min)
                min=mat[i][j];
            }
            
            arr[j]=min;
          }
    
    
    
    printf("%lf \n", arr[0]);
    
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

But when I print the matrix to my surprise, I see that the first few rows are partially filled and after 10th row all values are 0. like this

```
-5.670000 -8.260000 -10.700000 -14.130000 -5.150000 -9.850000 -13.160000 -6.830000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
-14.230000 -9.640000 -12.350000 -16.820000 -10.760000 -17.540000 -24.110000 -16.380000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
-0.870000 -0.770000 -4.720000 -8.000000 -1.220000 -2.900000 -5.060000 -0.110000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
-25.190000 -21.960000 -20.880000 -19.400000 -34.940000 -28.290000 -22.710000 -26.630000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
-0.940000 0.320000 1.570000 -3.560000 0.210000 0.340000 -3.770000 -2.640000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
-19.100000 -19.000000 -14.250000 -21.250000 -18.250000 -17.890000 -19.900000 -16.640000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
-2.380000 -1.880000 -2.930000 -6.430000 -5.340000 -5.200000 -10.960000 -7.860000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
4.120000 6.810000 4.890000 3.110000 5.630000 4.180000 5.350000 5.750000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
-21.450000 -22.410000 -23.990000 -14.130000 -24.540000 -22.970000 -24.410000 -25.730000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
-7.940000 -5.170000 -9.780000 -7.790000 -6.750000 -3.810000 -5.640000 -3.090000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Can someone help me and tell me what is wrong with my code that I am getting this behavior? Thank you.

Comment: How do you know the size of the matrix?

Comment: I am calculating it first by traversing the csv file. I have checked that as well. It is giving the right ans.

Comment: What values are in `r` and `c`? What's in `i` after you finish reading the file?

Comment: r is number of rows, which 430469 and c is number of columns which is 41. I have calculated them by traversing the csv file and they are correct

Comment: Attached the entire code now..

Comment: Does the problem occur if you reduce the input file to 100 lines with 10 columns?

Comment: @user3386109 I have not tried that tbh

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you can post a small sample of the CSV file that reproduces the problem. I can see many things in the code that could be improved, but nothing that can I point to as definitely *the* problem. For example, the number of columns is based solely on the number of columns in the last line of the file. Nothing in the code actually checks that all of the lines in the file have the same number of columns.

Comment: @user3386109
Hey, thanks for looking into it. I have solved it now.

Comment: @Mohan Singh Are you willing to tell us, what the problem was?

Comment: You don't `fclose(mf);` before `FILE *mf1=fopen("test.csv", "r");`. Don't call `fopen(mf1)`, just `rewind(mf)` and use `mf` for the read into your matrix as well.  Don't use `line1` that is 1/1000 the size of `line`, just reuse `line` for all reads. Add `'\n'` as a delimiter, so you call `strtok (..., ",\n")`